# Solr - Relevancy based on a range + outside the range

Tags: solr

In my query, I want to search for a price based on a range of values (ex. $500 - $1000) and return a fuzzy result set.

I can boost these values by doing price:[500 TO 1000]^10, but then it doesn't score $499 as any more relevant than $200.

I can create a boost function like:  recip(abs(sub(price,750)),1,1000,1000)^10, but this scores 501 as more relevant than 500.

Is there any way to have one boost function for $500-$1000 and another boost function for values outside that range?

Thanks,
Drew

***Edited for typo in the function***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`recip(abs(sub(price,750)),1,1000,1000)^10`

Use the mid-point of your range instead of the lower bound.

---

**Edit:** To answer the updated question:

Take a look at the [map](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#map) function here - you can map all prices between 500 and 1000 to 750 and then use that for boosting.  Something like:
`recip(abs(sub(map(price,500,1000,750),750)),1,1000,1000)^10`

This should score 600 and 700 the same but it will score 400 higher than 300.

Comment: That's actually what I meant to type.  Same question applies to this function though.  How can I make 500-1000 all the same relevancy, but anything outside that range have relevancy based on that function?

Comment: Have edited the answer - I think it should solve your problem.